# Printing at 11.5 inch in SSRS

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

I have an SSRS data report.  The interactive size and paper size, both are set to 8.5 X 12 inches.  But when I print this report, it does not print at 11.5 inches.
The bottom margin is also set to 0

Please advise.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge SSRS will let you have the 'body' of the report go over margins and this could be an issue but also the default size of portrait is 8.5 x 11.  I would do three things:

1. Go to the report designer and click anywhere in the blank space to ensure the 'Report' option toolbar displays.  Click it and you should have your orientation set up here to explicitly state Width: 8.5in, Height: 12in.  Set the margins explicitly here as well.  You may have already done this so I apologize if it is redundant
2. There is a toolbar menu view called 'Report' it contains an L with the point in the upper left.  This will show you inches marked out for you.  I would select that and see if there is anything obvious going over or under set requirements.
3. Check your printer options where this is being printed.  Does the printer know that the paper is not standard size?  Sometimes certain drivers will not use 100% of the page and use a tiny bit of padding or else assume you are using 8.5 x 11.  I would verify with something other than SSRS you can get the output you want as well.

Answer (score 0):

You might be using landscape mode change it to portrait mode and try it